# Submitting Multiple Forms Cross Domain

Tags: javascript, forms, cross-domain

**NOTE:** There are a million questions about using JavaScript to submit multiple forms, but trust me this one is different!

I need to submit multiple forms to another domain via POST.

The setup is as follows: There are multiple forms on one page, each with a unique action, each with target="_blank" so as to open the results in another window.  I have JS which hides the forms and creates a more condensed version that allows the user to select which forms to submit and click a single submit button.  I want to be able to then only submit the appropriate forms all in one fell swoop.

Right now I have the following code which is triggered when the uber form button is clicked.  It looks to see which checkboxes are checked, and attempts to submit the corresponding forms:

```
            submit_button.click(function() {
                var email = $("#uber_email").val();
                $('#lists input:checked').each(function() {
                    var form_id = $(this).val();
                    var form = $("#form" + form_id);
                    var form_email = form.find("input.email");
                    form_email.val(email);
                    form.submit();
                });
            });
```

Unfortunately this will only resolve the FINAL submit (i.e. only one form is clicked and only one popup renders).

Any thoughts?  Any better approaches?  I have no control over the server. I realize this is essentially cross site scripting, but I don't care!  I demand a work around!